# CUPS "Can't detect file type" after apt dist-upgrade

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, printing, cups, printer

I ran `apt dist-upgrade` on my Raspberry Pi and CUPS stopped working, so I can no longer print over the network. I tried restarting the CUPS service (and the whole system), and also removing and re-adding the printer via the web interface, but no dice. I can't figure out why the update has rendered printing inoperable.

Here is my CUPS web interface and the error log for a job I tried to print. I would post my CUPS config too, but I ran up against the SE character limit. I also tried enabling CUPS `debug2` logging, but that made my error log blow up to over 25000 lines (2.1M characters), which is not useful to me since I don't know what to grep for.

The closest hint I have is this line of my error log that looks important:

```
PID 2764 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
```

## Web interface error:

[image: CUPS web interface]

## Error log for failed job:

```
E [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Can't detect file type
E [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] The following messages were recorded from 19:36:50 to 19:36:50
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Adding start banner page "none".
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Queued on "EPSON_Stylus_CX8400" by "chronos".
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] File of type application/vnd.cups-pdf queued by "chronos".
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Adding end banner page "none".
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] time-at-processing=1523129810
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] 2 filters for job:
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] rastertogutenprint.5.2 (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/EPSON_Stylus_CX8400, cost 100)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] job-sheets=none,none
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] argv[0]="EPSON_Stylus_CX8400"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] argv[1]="507"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] argv[2]="chronos"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] argv[3]="Untitled"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] argv[4]="1"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] argv[5]="document-name-supplied=Loving-Kindness\ Recitation\ -\ Google\ Docs Duplex=None job-uuid=urn:uuid:8d51be2e-8055-37c6-4e5f-bf8d2f56c0bd media=na_letter_8.5x11in PageSize=Letter print-color-mode=color sides=one-sided job-originating-host-name=10.0.1.187 time-at-creation=1523129810 time-at-processing=1523129810"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00507-001"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@raspberrypi-3"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.7.5"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[19]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/EPSON_Stylus_CX8400.ppd"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=usb://EPSON/Stylus%20CX8400?serial=9B0000000000000000&interface=1"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=EPSON Stylus CX8400"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION=Max's Room"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[26]="PRINTER=EPSON_Stylus_CX8400"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gziptoany (PID 2763)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 2764)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertogutenprint.5.2 (PID 2765)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 2766)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Loading USB quirks from "/usr/share/cups/usb".
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Loaded 113 quirks.
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Printing on printer with URI: usb://EPSON/Stylus%20CX8400?serial=9B0000000000000000&interface=1
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] libusb_get_device_list=5
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Set job-printer-state-message to "Can't detect file type", current level=ERROR
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] PID 2763 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gziptoany) exited with no errors.
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Printer found with device ID: MFG:EPSON;CMD:ESCPL2,BDC,D4,D4PX,ESCPR1;MDL:Stylus CX8400;CLS:PRINTER;DES:EPSON Stylus CX8400; Device URI: usb://EPSON/Stylus%20CX8400?serial=9B0000000000000000&interface=1
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Device protocol: 2
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] PID 2764 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Sending data to printer.
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: ============================================================
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: 5.2.10 Starting
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: command line: EPSON_Stylus_CX8400 '507' 'chronos' 'Untitled' '1' <args>
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: using PPD file /etc/cups/ppd/EPSON_Stylus_CX8400.ppd
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: CUPS option count is 10 (309 bytes)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 0 document-name-supplied = Loving-Kindness Recitation - Google Docs
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 1 Duplex = None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 2 job-originating-host-name = 10.0.1.187
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 3 job-uuid = urn:uuid:8d51be2e-8055-37c6-4e5f-bf8d2f56c0bd
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 4 media = na_letter_8.5x11in
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 5 PageSize = Letter
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 6 print-color-mode = color
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 7 sides = one-sided
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 8 time-at-creation = 1523129810
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:  CUPS option 9 time-at-processing = 1523129810
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: Driver Epson Stylus CX8400
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: Using fd 0
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: Set options:
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set string Quality to Standard
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set special string Quality to Standard
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting PageSize to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting MediaType to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting InputSlot to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting Duplex to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CDInnerRadius to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CDOuterDiameter to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CDInnerDiameter to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CDXAdjustment to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CDYAdjustment to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CDAllowOtherMedia to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting Resolution to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set string InkType to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set special string InkType to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting UseGloss to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set string InkSet to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set special string InkSet to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set string PrintingDirection to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set special string PrintingDirection to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set bool FullBleed to False (0)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set string Weave to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set special string Weave to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting OutputOrder to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting AlignmentPasses to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting AlignmentChoices to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting InkChange to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting AlternateAlignmentPasses to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting AlternateAlignmentChoices to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting SupportsPacketMode to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting InterchangeableInk to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting InkChannels to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting RawChannelNames to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting ChannelNames to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting PrintingMode to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting RawChannels to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CyanHueCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting MagentaHueCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting YellowHueCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting BlueHueCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting OrangeHueCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting RedHueCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting GreenHueCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_max_hres to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_max_vres to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_min_hres to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_min_vres to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_nozzles to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_black_nozzles to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_fast_nozzles to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_min_nozzles to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_min_black_nozzles to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_min_fast_nozzles to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_nozzle_start to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_black_nozzle_start to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_fast_nozzle_start to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_nozzle_separation to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_black_nozzle_separation to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_fast_nozzle_separation to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_separation_rows to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_max_paper_width to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_max_paper_height to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_min_paper_width to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_min_paper_height to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_max_imageable_width to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_max_imageable_height to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_extra_feed to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_pseudo_separation_rows to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_base_separation to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_resolution_scale to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_initial_vertical_offset to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_black_initial_vertical_offset to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_max_black_resolution to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_zero_margin_offset to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_extra_720dpi_separation to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_micro_left_margin to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_min_horizontal_position_alignment to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_base_horizontal_position_alignment to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_bidirectional_upper_limit to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_physical_channels to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_left_margin to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_right_margin to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_top_margin to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_bottom_margin to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_ink_type to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_bits to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_base_res to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_alignment_passes to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_alignment_choices to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_alternate_alignment_passes to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_alternate_alignment_choices to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_cd_x_offset to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_cd_y_offset to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_cd_page_width to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_cd_page_height to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_paper_extra_bottom to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_preinit_sequence to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_preinit_remote_sequence to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_postinit_remote_sequence to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting escp2_vertical_borderless_sequence to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting BandEnhancement to 'None'
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting PaperThickness to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting VacuumIntensity to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting FeedSequence to 'None'
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting PrintMethod to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting PlatenGap to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting FeedAdjustment to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set string ColorCorrection to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set special string ColorCorrection to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting ChannelBitDepth to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting InputImageType to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting STPIOutputType to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting STPIRawChannels to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting SimpleGamma to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set bool LinearContrast to False (0)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting LUTDumpFile to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CyanCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting MagentaCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting YellowCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting BlackCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting RedCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting GreenCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting BlueCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting WhiteCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting HueMap to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting SatMap to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting LumMap to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting GCRCurve to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh0 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh1 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh2 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh3 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh4 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh5 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh6 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh7 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh8 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh9 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh10 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh11 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh12 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh13 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh14 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh15 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh16 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh17 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh18 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh19 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh20 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh21 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh22 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh23 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh24 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh25 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh26 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh27 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh28 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh29 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh30 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh31 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh32 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh33 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh34 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh35 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh36 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh37 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh38 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh39 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh40 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh41 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh42 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh43 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh44 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh45 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh46 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh47 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh48 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh49 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh50 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh51 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh52 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh53 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh54 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh55 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh56 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh57 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh58 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh59 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh60 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh61 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh62 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting CurveCh63 to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set string DitherAlgorithm to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set special string DitherAlgorithm to None
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set string ImageType to TextGraphics
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:   Set special string ImageType to TextGraphics
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting JobMode to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint:     Not setting PageNumber to (null)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: End options
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: About to start printing loop.
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: stats 0B, 0.440u, 0.010s, 0.426el
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Gutenprint: ============================================================
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Sent 0 bytes...
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] PID 2765 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertogutenprint.5.2) exited with no errors.
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] PID 2766 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] End of messages
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] printer-state=3(idle)
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] printer-state-message="Sending data to printer."
D [07/Apr/2018:19:36:50 +0000] [Job 507] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Comment: By the way, I am posting on this linux stack exchange and not the raspberry pi stack exchange because I don't see any reason this question is specific to the raspberry pi.

Comment: have you run `apt-get update` before upgrading your system?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Yep. I just did another `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade` today to make sure.

Comment: have you tried to print another file? perhaps another pdf file or a more simple text file?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Just tried printing a completely unrelated PDF that I downloaded online, and got the same error.

Comment: Also, `df` shows that none of my disks have run out of space.

Comment: Also, it fails with the same error on a pristine install of Debian Stretch.

Comment: i advice you to wait some days or perhaps even better to open a bug here https://www.debian.org/Bugs/

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing a clean install of Rasbian Stretch Lite and the problem persisted from both Chrome OS and Windows 10 network prints, so I tried installing the official Epson Stylus CX8400 driver on Windows instead of using the built-in driver, and I was able to get a page to print. Then I installed [google cloud print connector](https://github.com/google/cloud-print-connector/wiki/Install) on the Pi and linked it to my Google account, and was able to get printing working from Chrome OS as well.

I don't know what the change was that made CUPS stop working in the first place (maybe it was actually a Chrome OS update I missed that happened to occur on the same day), but that's how I fixed it for my use case.